# How to use the same context manager across different methods?

Tags: python-3.x, contextmanager

I am trying to implement a class which uses python context manager ..

Though i understand the general concept of **enter** and **exit** i dont see how to use the same context manager across multiple code blocks.

for example take the below case

```
@contextmanager 
def backupContext(input)
   try:
     return xyz
   finally
     revert (xyz)

class do_something:

   def __init__(self):
         self.context = contextVal

   def doResourceOperation_1():
       with backupContext(self.context) as context:
           do_what_you_want_1(context)

   def doResourceOperation_2():
       with backupContext(self.context) as context:
         do_what_you_want_2(context)
```

I am invoking the context managers twice..Suppose i want to do only once.. during the **init** and use the same context manager object to do all my operations and then finally when the object is deleted i want to do the revert operation how should i go about it?

Should i call **enter** and **exit** manually instead of using the with statement?